# Problem with limit of recursive sequence having the actual index "n" in denominator.

Tags: limits

The given sequence is: 
$$ a_1 = 1; \quad a_{n+1} = \frac{2a_n}{n+1} $$
 $n$ is natural.
What is the limit if $n\to\infty$?
Please help!

Comment: Have you tried working out the first few terms, and looking for a pattern?

Comment: Well it gets messy but it tends to zero. Unfortunately I need the steps of the proof, not just the initial (right) guess as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find that,
whenever there is an $n$
or $n+1$ in a recurrence,
throwing a
$n!$ or $(n+1)!$ somewhere usually helps.

You have
$a_{n+1} 
= \frac{2a_n}{n+1}
$.

If we multiply by
$(n+1)!$,
this becomes
$(n+1)!a_{n+1} 
= 2n!a_n
$.
(Note that multiplying by $n!$
or dividing by
$n!$ do not work.)

Letting
$b_n
=n!a_n
$,
we get
$b_{n+1}
=2b_n
$,
which you should be able to solve.

Then get $a_n$
by
$\frac{b_n}{n!}
$.

Comment: This "throwing an n! somewhere" works a little too well here.... I'm suspicious.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! Sorry I cannot upvote yet:D.

Comment: If it didn't work, I wouldn't have answered.

Comment: Besides, if something works "too well", it is probably a homework problem.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have sorted out the closed form for $a_n$, you can try to determine convergence of yhe sum $\sum_n \frac{2^n}{n!}$. If it convrges, then the limit of the series is obvious.

Comment: Thank You too kind Sir! Your intake was crutial for me:D!

Comment: You are welcome